# How to add a style in line of jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to know what is the best way to add a style in the code below so that the readonly textboxs are coloured grey?

```
$("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").val(t_marksHtml).attr('readonly', true);
```

Comment: readonly boxes are greyed out per default in decent browsers?

Comment: Are we classing firefox as decent browsers lol, because it isn't doing it in firefox. But that maybe because in my code depending on situation, some text inputs are readonly and some are not

Comment: @Christoph only `disabled` inputs are greyed out by default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
 $("selector for textbox").addClass("read-only-state");
```

and apply css in .read-only-state class

```
 .read-only-state{
  color:#333;
  background:grey;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in pure CSS:

```
textarea[readonly]{
  color: grey;
}
```

or (better yet) left to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use pure CSS?

```
input[readonly]
{
    background-color: grey
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/DqjAC/

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
textarea[readonly]
{
    background: #999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just use attribute selector

```
$("input:[readonly]").css({"background":"#666"});
```

But its better to do with CSS only as

```
input[readonly]{
  background: #666;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

basically, use this for all html tags with readonly attribute.

```
$("[readonly]").css("background-color","#CCC");
```

only input tags

```
$("input:[readonly]").css("background-color","#CCC");
```